# Example for singular Lagrange dynamics giving rise to a primary constraint

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, constrained-dynamics

There is vast literature about constraint dynamics, but the available material is quite abstract and it feels to read about things which are far from reality.

Is there a simple example, where I can study a particular case, where

$\frac{\partial^2L}{\partial \dot q_i \partial \dot q_j}$

is singular and the velocities $\dot q_i$ cannot be expressed by the canonical momenta $p_i$?

I would like to see an example, where a primary constraint gives rise to secondary constraints. But since the Lagrangian must obviously be linear in velocities, I cannot figure out what that could be.

Comment: This post (v1) seems like a list question since there is not a unique answer.

Comment: I removed what you regarded as list.

Answer (score 2):

The most famous example of what you want is the symmetrized Dirac Lagrangian:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found good examples [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_bracket).